# How to view text in tables that contains Unicode characters from the Chinese and Arabic alphabets

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have managed to import a CSV file that contained Chinese, Arabic, and English characters into a SQL Server table.

However, when I go to view the contents of the table I am getting characters like `Ù†Ø§Ø²Ù†ÛŒÙ†` instead of `نازنین`

How can I get SQL Server to show me the Unicode characters in the table when I do a simple select?

Update:

**Database Collation:** Latin1_General_CI_AS

**Column Datatype:** nvarchar

**Import Method:** I imported the CSV using the Import Wizard and used the UTF-8 encoding

Comment: What is the data type of the column? What is the collation? How exactly did you "manage to import" it? Do you still have the file so you can import it again? I don't think this is about viewing the text, I think it's already mangled at rest.

Comment: The datatype of the column is nvarchar. The collation of the database is Latin1_General_CI_AS. I imported the CSV using the Import Wizard and used the UTF-8 encoding. When I was doing this all the characters looked correct in the Preview. Yes I have the file so I can import it again.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support UTF-8 directly, and it only supports UTF-16 with specific collations (try `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC`).

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you for this. In the end it turns out that it would be better not to allow such characters at all because they will mess up the URLs that are made from the names. I also don't have the ability/authority to change the collation of the database unfortunately :(